# Selenium disable plugins in firefox profile

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

Can someone tell me how to disable plugins for my customer firefox profile using Java? I have found a few sites showing to add add-ons but nothing about disable plugins.

My firefox profile:

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",reportFolder);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/pdf,application/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStartinge",false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown",false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.useToolkitUI",true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.firstRun", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

The problem is by default this has some plugins enabled. Adobe acrobat, google update, java, microsoft office, flash, shockwave for director and silverlight.

I need to disable some of these as they are messing up my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are creating a profile that explicitly installs firefox extensions/plugins Selenium  Webdriver will create a blank profile and use that.

Can you show us what code you are using to call the FF driver?

Comment: Hi Farlan I have updated the question with my code. Unfortunately the blank profile created does have some plugins enabled.

Comment: can you specify which are messing with your tests?

Comment: Acrobat is the one that seems to be causing most of them

Comment: try adding this preference: `"plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf"`

Comment: Thank you Farlan adding that to my profile fixed the problem.

Comment: Depending on your Firefox version, you may have to include several additional MIME types in addition to application/pdf:
  `firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml");`