# Python Selenium - How to disable plugins for Firefox profile?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do you disable the plugins in a Firefox profile, in python code? A Google search didn't return anything useful in Python.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference(...)
```

Comment: Have a look on the link it might help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838853/selenium-disable-plugins-in-firefox-profile

Comment: Thanks I've already saw that a few times. However, it just talks about disabling a specific plugin. I want to disable all of them.

Comment: @macdonjo: Not sure if this works, can you try to invoke Firefox in Safemode ...which disables all plugin's by default